# Is anybody working on a high level standard library for C++

Tags: c++

STL/Boost cover all the low level stuff.

But what about the higher level concepts?

Windows: We have multiple windowing libs

- KDE(Qt)
- Gnome
- Motif(C but written in OO style)
- MS Windows
- etc

But is anybody working on a unified standard for windowing?
Something that wrapped all the above would be acceptable. (even if it only accessed the common stuff it would be a starting point).

Networking:
There are a couple out there (including the Boost low level stuff).
But is there anybody working on a Service based network layer?

All the other stuff that Java/C# have in their standard libraries.
The stuff that makes it simpler for a beginner to jump in and say Wow done and it works everywhere (nearly).

Anyway. Here hoping there are some cool projects out there.

**Edit**

Maybe there is not one.
But if there are a couple that could be bundled together as a starting point (and potentially modified over time (where is that deprecated keyword)) into a nice consolidated whole.

Note: Windows is just a small part of what I am looking for. The Java/C# languages consolidate a lot more under the hood than just the GUI. What would be a good set of libraries to get all the functionality in one place.

Comment: +1 favorited for future reference also ;)

Comment: How would something become a "unified standard"? Do you mean making it part of ISO standard, or what? (keep in mind that Boost isn't "standard" in that sense, though some bits of it made their way into standard C++ library).

Comment: @Pavel: Like boost. You make somthing so useful that everbody uses it and practically becomes a defacto standard. For me writting code without boost is a real pain (though it's nice that some of it also made it into std::tr1). But I practically expect every C++ developer to have boost installed.

Comment: Martin: yes, I've seen plenty of places that use C++ heavily but don't rely on Boost for various reasons, so I wouldn't quite call it a standard. In any case, the problem with UI is that people widely disagree on how to do it "right", so until then several libraries with different design goals is what we're going to have.

Comment: @Martin York, at my first company STL wasn't even used.

Comment: Since it's difficult to envision a definite answer to this question, should not it be a Community Wiki thing ? I put in favs anyway for future reference :)

Comment: I agree that Java developers are lucky to have one, single, unified GUI framework in AWT... err..., I mean Swing. Or is it SWT? Or JavaFX? Mmm... maybe they don't, finally. But .NET does, in WinForms. Or is it WPF?

Comment: Don't forget that MIDP had its own GUI too. I'm not sure the C++ standard committee would really go for a "standard" library that was expected not to exist on devices less than 6 inches long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Poco C++](http://pocoproject.org/) project aims to deliver all that you ask, except for Windowing:

> The POCO C++ Libraries aim to be for
>   network-centric, cross-platform C++
>   software development what Apple's
>   Cocoa is for Mac development, or Ruby
>   on Rails is for Web development — a
>   powerful, yet easy to use platform to
>   build your applications upon.

Answer (score 14):

There are too big differences between platforms to get a definitive C++ standard for GUI programming. I think [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) is about as close as you will get in the forseeable future. [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org) is another popular choise, but as I understand it, they are using less modern c++ features.

As for networking, I think you are being kind of vague. If you mean web services over HTTP, I would have a look at [Pion](http://pion.org/projects/pion-network-library).

Comment: Yes - several other projects also have nice networking components. I just don't know what the asker is looking for.

Comment: With Qxt on top of Qt, you get decent RPC and HTTP/Web support.

Comment: Yes I was being delibrately vague in the hopes of finding libraries that I had not heard about.

Answer (score 11):

Well it is *almost* 2010 and C++ *almost* has threads.

I'll probably get slammed for this but C++ moves too slow - to its own detriment and its user base.  I readily acknowledge the difficulty of the technical and political issues involved but that's still the dirty reality of it.  The language can't build in higher level concepts when it takes 5-10 years to agree on and implement the building blocks.

The reasons for this have endlessly debated but the sad truth is that C++ has relegated itself to a niche language.  I like C++ but I look at the progress C#, Java, and even Python and Ruby have made over the last 5 years and I increasingly question whether C++ is worth the effort.

Comment: Why would including threads in the standard be a prerequisite to a portable windowing abstraction?

Comment: @Eric: I think he was just commenting on the processes as a whole. And too a degree I agree. @Duck: But as a result C++ is technically a much nicer language than some some out there. But the slow pace of change has left us wallowing a bit.

Comment: @Eric It was just an example of how long it takes to get anything standardized in C++.

Comment: I can agree on some things but for threading I'll drop a note that hopefully makes sense. Remember though that all other environments are implemented with C or C++ and then some real ugly glueing..

Comment: I'd consider myself lucky that it hasn't, otherwise it would have messed up with memory models as much as Java, and to lesser extent C#. These are known artifacts in those environments. Second, rest assured that the people doing the CPUs are telling C++ compiler guys what to do and how.In that sense, both Java and C# 'rushed in'.You could have used posix or nt or boost wrapped one for years and most compilers gave you freebies that are executing far better than in VMs and their pools on top of OS bits.It is niche though,however, that's not its focus, it's a tool for any kind of idea,ie.Rubies

Comment: The speed of standard C++ development has nothing to do with external frameworks, Boost is not part of the standards process. This is a ridiculous argument.

Comment: I think Duck definitely has a point here, but I think I'd disagree with C++ being a niche language, but maybe that's me being a little defensive or something.  It's not one of the shiny, new sparkly tools on the block, but I don't think it's quite in the niche category either.

Comment: @Andy: I don't see what you are commenting on?

Comment: @Michael: I would afree with that. C++ is everywhere I look. Its not the old grandad (C) but its not the nifty new language (C#). Only time will tell how the language holds up against developer needs and hardware paradiagm shifts (what happened to Dataflow processors).

Comment: A "niche" language wouldn't have such a big user base. You could tell it's more suited for some specific kind of software developpement, yes, but "niche" is kind of wrong. It's like being a game developper and saying that Java is a niche programming language because it's not really used or only in phones...for games anyway. In reallity, like some other language we all heard about, it's almost everywhere in specific kind of developpement.

Answer (score 5):

Qt might be the only framework complete enough to be what you suggest.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there's some kind of keyword lookup driving the advertising here because I'm seeing a [REALbasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/) ad, which is what I generally use for cross-platform GUI's nowadays.

I have spent a lot of time over the last 15 years working in C++ GUI's including retailing my own [portability layer](http://www.pp2mfc.com/) for CodeWarrior PowerPlant and working on the two Macintosh-based GUI code generators, including adding Windows generation to [AppMaker](http://www.appmakerx.com/). I've worked with wxWidgets, mainly wxPython. So, my opinion on difficulties in cross-platform GUI is fairly well-qualified :-)

Cross-platform GUI frameworks are hard to the point of nearly impossible without significant compromise - the issues come down to subtle matters of *behavior* which generally bother users at a level where some of them can't quantify but know that the application *doesn't feel right*. This is a lot harder to fix than just rendering native controls.

I started using REALbasic because their framework does a better job of getting the feel right than anything else I'd tried (I didn't get into Qt because of the expensive commercial license).

The reason it has taken so long for things to evolve is nothing to do with the C++ world moving slowly, it's just an intractable problem. The very best cross-platform Java apps do some stuff conditionally for OS/X and it is still screamingly obvious to an experienced user that they are not a native Mac app, although some are very usable and come pretty close to looking native - [Oxygen XML editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) and [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/) are two of my favourites.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is achievable to make a really comprehensive portable GUI library. Operating systems are just too different. Can you imagine a GUI library that would cover everything from iPhone to Windows 7 and wouldn't feel wierd on any of them?

Comment: Sorry, could not resist: Java GUIs feel weird on all platforms, but that did not stop them :)

Comment: Which is one reason the Java is now a mainly server side language (before anybody jumps me: not exclusively but that's its main nich now).

Answer (score 3):

A Boost gui library comes up occasionally.
The general opinion seems to be that the problems is too wide (are you targeting cellphones, FPS games or CAD workstations) and that it is too much work - Qt/wxWidgets has taken 10years.

see http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/09/94453.php for a discussion.

It would have been nice because GUI usually means cross platform and threads, so all the GUI toolkits have invented their own cross platform,filesystem and thread classes. On the other hand if a standard GUI had been introduced in C++ it would probably look like TK !

Answer (score 3):

What's so great about standardization ?  Sure, if novice coders want to download one SDK to build portable apps, let them download Qt (or something similar) and forever remain within it's fine walled environment.  But it'd be a tragedy if the C++ world revolved around that one library and boost and POCO and wxWidgets and clutter and blitz++ and eigen and and 101 other wonderful things (yes, gtkmm and ACE even) were stifled at birth because the gatekeepers of The Standard Library didn't see fit to admit them.

Diversity is good I think (although when dealing with it, it helps to have a good package manager; I've spent hours setting up build dependencies on Windows which just needed a few seconds of apt-getting on Debian).

Comment: Diversity is good I admit, but would not you be grateful to have a high-level, easy-to-use, high-performance library for GUI or for Threading or for Web Services ? That's what are great with defacto standards, they become such because users find them useful, not because they are given to them by a magnanimous committee.

Comment: Personally I'm glad all of the boost::thread and Intel TBB and Qt thread libraries exist (and OpenMP for C++ too).  All of them have their own strengths and areas of applicability.  If one was clearly superior to the others, it probably would emerge as a defacto standard.  But the fact a defacto standard hasn't emerged isn't necessarily a bad thing, or mean that there's a desperate need to subsume all of them into some new all-encompasing API which tries to be all things to all users so that a de-facto standard can emerge.

Answer (score 1):

[ACE](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) is great for concurrent communication and networking.

Comment: Yep. I like ACE. Though internally some of the code is a bit doddgey (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

For cross platform windowing, there's [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). (formerly wxWindows).

Answer (score 0):

Only everybody and his brother, but hardly any of them actually get anywhere.